# Determining coefficients of a Dirichlet series based on values on a vertical line

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series

Let us suppose we have a Dirichlet series
$$ D(s) = \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{a(n)}{n^s},$$
and that we know the values of $D(\tfrac{1}{2} + im)$ for $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. Can we recover the coefficients $a(n)$ by our knowledge of $D(\tfrac{1}{2} + im)$?

It's easy to recover the coefficients if we had values of the form $D(m)$ for $m \gg 1$, by repeatedly taking limits, subtracting known terms, and dividing out denominators. But what about in vertical lines?

Comment: What is special about $1/2+im$?

Comment: @July Nothing, except that it just so happens to be the "critical line" in many Dirichlet series that people like. I really ask the question for any vertical line with none in particular in mind.

Comment: Yes, but the critical line usually appears after analytic continuation. 

Anyway, not exactly what you are asking for, but related: there is a way to recover the Dirichlet coefficients from a vertical line via averaging on it, namely $a(n)=\lim_{T\to\infty}\frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^TD(\sigma+it)n^{\sigma+it}dt$ for an arbitrary $\sigma$ in the half-plane of absolute convergence. I will have to think about a discrete version of that, perhaps at least some reasonable approximation might be possible.